# How to dispose of temp screen rendering for bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, filestream

It works draws text of a number and name on a raffle ticket and saves it in the customer's file correctly. 
But then returns me = not to the web page but a full black screen with the picture of the ticket. 
No way to make it go away and get back to the web page except rerun the page. I tried writing to a memory stream but it would not save it correctly if I remove `Response.OutputStream` and change it to a memory stream in this line `= bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

It took less time to learn how to use the graphic system from scratch than discover how to make it not render to the screen. Lost!

```
protected string RaffelTicketWrImg(string sOrigBlankTicketImg, string sTicketNbr)
{
    //creating a image object   
    System.Drawing.Image bitmap = (System.Drawing.Image)Bitmap.FromFile(sOrigBlankTicketImg); // set image    
                                                                                              //draw the image object using a Graphics object   
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    //Set the alignment based on the coordinates      
    StringFormat stringformat = new StringFormat();
    stringformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    stringformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    //stringformat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;

    StringFormat stringformat2 = new StringFormat();
    stringformat2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    stringformat2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    //Set the font color/format/size etc..     
    System.Drawing.Color StringColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");//direct color adding   
    System.Drawing.Color StringColor2 = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");//customise color adding   
    string sWriteThis = sTicketNbr;//Your Text On Image   
    string sWriteThis2 = sTicketNbr;//Your Text On Image   
                                    //Ticket Size 1.26" by 2.62"
                                    //Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

    double dLen = ((sTicketNbr.Length / 2) * 13) / 2;
    int iPixcels = bitmap.Width;
    double iPoints = iPixcels * g.DpiX / Convert.ToInt16(72); //72 / 96;
    int iX_Hroz = Convert.ToInt16((iPoints / 2) - Convert.ToInt16(dLen));
    int iY_Vert = 30;
    g.DrawString(sWriteThis, new Font("arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(iX_Hroz, iY_Vert), stringformat); Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

    iY_Vert = 222;

    g.DrawString(sWriteThis2, new Font("arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(StringColor2), new Point(iX_Hroz, iY_Vert), stringformat2); Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

    sWriteThis = txPersonNamed.Text;//Your Text On Image   
                                    //Ticket Size 1.26" by 2.62"
    string[] words = sWriteThis.Split(' ');
    iX_Hroz = 15;
    iY_Vert = 90;

    stringformat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    stringformat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        g.DrawString(word.ToString(), new Font("arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold),
            new SolidBrush(StringColor), new Point(iX_Hroz, iY_Vert), stringformat);
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        iY_Vert += 20;
    }

    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    string sSaveFile = Vars.TicketPath + "/" + sTicketNbr + ".jpg";

    if (txEmail.Text.Length == 0) //Test Diaplay
    {
        if (File.Exists(sSaveFile)) File.Delete(sSaveFile);
    }

    bitmap.Save(sSaveFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // Release memory used by the Graphics object
    // and the bitmap.
    g.Dispose();
    bitmap.Dispose();

    // Send the output to the client.
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: What is your question and what are you trying to do? Saving an image to a memory stream works flawlessly.

Comment: Greetings RBT. The above works saved to Response.OutputStream but leaves the rendered photo on the display. Covering the webpage. I do not want to see it just write them to a file for email attachments. 
Here is my code for the memory stream version excerts. But when I replace response.outputstream with mStream it displays and write a corrupt file.eg);

Comment: Here is the memory stream excerpt.
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sOrigBlankTicketImg, FileMode.Open);
            System.Drawing.Image bitmap = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream);

            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

            bitmap.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            fileStream.Close();..

            bitmap.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            string sSaveFile = Vars.TicketPath + "/" + sTicketNbr + ".jpg";

            bitmap.Save(sSaveFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpg);